# Remove Vimeo replay button

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api, vimeo-player

First off I do apologies if this isn't the kind of question I should be asking on stackoverflow. I'm trying to remove the small 'replay' button in the bottom left of a Vimeo video after it's finished playing. Or at least just keep the controls visible (either or).

I've been through all the documentation related to player.js on Git and gone through the SDK doc's related to the API and I can't find anything related to the replay button / event. I can trigger items after the ended event. But this will not do anything within the player because it's contained in an iframe. Any pointing in the right direction here will be of great help. I've also google searched and it's drawing a blank.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for this one just incase someone searches for the same thing. The simple solution was to destroy the player on ending.

```
player.on('ended', function () {
    player.destroy();
    player = new Vimeo.Player('video', options);
});
```

Hope this may help someone else out.